# TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler

Tags: .net-assembly

Is there any way that i can overcome this error:

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport' threw an exception.'

TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler' from assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

The Framework that i was using is 4.7 and i was getting this error, when i try to get this value. SmsClient smsClient = new SmsClient(connectionString);

Here i've tried Bind Redirect to the latest version & the particular Version mentioned in the error 4.0.0.0 .

But still i was getting the same. Any suggestions for this...